# Django filtering bey a child of a child

Tags: python, django-queryset

I have these 3 models **Stock**, **Product** and **ProductDepartment**. I need to filter **Stock** using **ProductDepartment** id.

```
class Stock(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    selling_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=22, decimal_places=4, blank=True, null=True)
        ...

class Product(models.Model):
    bar_code = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='N/A', blank=True, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    product_code = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='N/A', blank=True, null=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(DrugCategory, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    department = models.ForeignKey(ProductDepartment, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    ...

class ProductDepartment(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    shortcut = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,blank=True, null=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True,blank=True, null=True)
    deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I have been using loops then append, but i end up with a list which is more complicated to manipulate the way i want to. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You don't filter by a child of a child, but by a paremt of a parent:

```
Stock.objects.filter(product__department_id=department_id)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked. Just one more question: If i have a calculated field (calculated in models), can i use it to filter in views? I see it works well in templates but the calculated field is not recognized in the views even after i do this: total_price = property(total_price)

Comment: No, since filtering happens at the database, you will need to work with `.annotate(..)` to calculate this in the query.